# Free Visual Studio XML Documentation Authoring Tool

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xml-documentation

I'm looking for a free authoring tool to author XML Documentation in Visual Studio 2010.

I know [Document! X](http://www.innovasys.com/products/dx2010/overview.aspx)

but i'm looking for a free or open-source similar tool.

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [SandCastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) with [SandCastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/)

> Sandcastle, created by Microsoft, is a tool used for creating MSDN-style documentation from .NET assemblies and their associated XML comments files. The current version is the May 2008 release. It is command line based and has no GUI front-end, project management features, or an automated build process like those that you can find in NDoc. The Sandcastle Help File Builder was created to fill in the gaps, provide the missing NDoc-like features that are used most often, and provide graphical and command line based tools to build a help file in an automated fashion.

*(Ayende wrote a blog post on [API Documentation generation](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/09/20/generating-api-documentation.aspx))*

Comment: I'm not looking for a generation tool (i'm currently using Sandcastle with SHFB). I'm looking for a graphical (Plugin/VS Extension ?) authoring tool in order to edit comments in source code ref/exemples etc..

Comment: GhostDoc can add TODO optionally at generated comments, so one could use the Tasks pane to navigate easily and edit each one. I think it is only at Pro edition available, but better check their product comparison tables

Answer (score 1):

although I haven't used it personally, I've heard good things about doxygen - http://www.doxygen.nl/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any free "wysiwyg" documentation tools like DocumentX.

However, for entering and updating the documentation comments (for either SandCastle or Doxygen use) you may find my addin, [AtomineerUtils Pro Documentation](http://www.atomineerutils.com/) handy. (It's not free, but it is very inexpensive and does a huge amount to reduce the time/work involved in documenting source code)