# How do I make xml documentation in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, xml-documentation

How can I generate documentation of my C# web application in Visual Studio 2012, like Eclipse does?

Comment: What have you tried? (It's somewhat unusual to need to publish the XML documentation for a web application, IMO. Class libraries, sure - but what's going to *refer* to a web application?)

Comment: @SaniHuttunen but this is not important, just because he's the guy he can be rude?

Comment: Ok @SaniHuttunen!! Sorry Jon! I think that VS2012 has the same tools of Eclipse to make documentation!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Visual Studio go to tools menu -> extension manager... then in extension manager click on online gallery (on the left), then type in the top right search box the text... [ghostdoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) 
 It's a very nice document helper.

Answer (score 1):

You can comment your code using xml comments

```
/// <summary>
///  This class performs an important function.
/// </summary>
```

and then generate xml documentation after compiling the /doc.
Here is the source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx

also I advixe you to use Sandcastle with its Help File Builder which is a very powerful tool:
http://shfb.codeplex.com/

Comment: Sandcastle is now maintained outside Microsoft and has a page specifically about web projects http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/html/94c7f744-9b90-4254-93ab-9b15f47d9f42.htm

Answer (score 0):

Please inspect this post: [Free Visual Studio XML Documentation Authoring Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821807/free-visual-studio-xml-documentation-authoring-tool)

They advice [sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ghostdoc  for XML documentation.

http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx

You can use sandcastle to create a Help document

http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/